# How to set tableview to place stores nearest to my current location using geopoint in Cloud Firestore?

Tags: swift, firebase, uitableview, google-cloud-firestore, location

What im trying to do is organize my cells by the store nearest my current location using Geopoint in Cloud Firestore

I have looked all over stack, but I can't find how to set the tableview in the ViewController to show the flower store nearest me from my current location using geopoint in Cloud Firestore

this is what I have currently to set up the data to pass to the VC for it to organize the data from Firestore to the stores nearest to my current location

below I have an image of the collection in my Firestore and an Image of my ViewController for how my app is set up

[image]
[image]

```
import Foundation
import UIKit

class Store {
    var id: String
    var storeName: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var location: ??

    init(id: String,
         storeName: String,
         imageUrl: String,
         location:??) {                                              //

        self.id = id
        self.storeName = storeName
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.location = location                                    //
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let storeName = dictionary["storeName"] as? String ?? ""
        let imageUrl =  dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""
        let location =  dictionary["location"] as? String ?? ""    //

        self.init(id: id,
                  storeName: storeName,
                  imageUrl: imageUrl,
                  location: location)                              //
    }

}
```

---

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    var locationManager: CLLocationManager?

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    var stores: [Store] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        fetchStores { (stores) in
            self.stores = stores
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    func fetchStores(_ completion: @escaping ([Store]) -> Void) {
        let ref = Firestore.firestore().collection("storeName")
            ref.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard error == nil, let snapshot = snapshot, !snapshot.isEmpty else {
                return
            }
            completion(snapshot.documents.compactMap( {Store(dictionary: $0.data())} ))
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didChangeAuthorization status: CLAuthorizationStatus) {
        if status == .authorizedWhenInUse {
            if CLLocationManager.isMonitoringAvailable(for: CLBeaconRegion.self){
                if CLLocationManager.isRangingAvailable() {
                    // do Stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: It doesn't look like `ViewController` has a property called `stores`. If it does, can you include it in the code so we can see it?

Comment: sorry typo just updated my code now it does have the stores property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe this answer should work, though I may have missed something.

What you'll want to do is make the `location` property in `Store` of type `CLLocationCoordinate2D`. This requires importing `CoreLocation`. You also want to add a property called `distanceFromUser` that makes use of `CLLocation.distance(from:)` method to find the distance in meters between the user's current location and the store's location:

```swift
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class Store {
    var id: String
    var storeName: String
    var imageUrl: String
    var location: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var distanceFromUser: Double

    init(id: String,
         storeName: String,
         imageUrl: String,
         location: CLLocationCoordinate2D) {

        self.id = id
        self.storeName = storeName
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        self.location = location  
        self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))!
    }

    convenience init(dictionary: [String : Any]) {
        let id = dictionary["id"] as? String ?? ""
        let storeName = dictionary["storeName"] as? String ?? ""
        let imageUrl =  dictionary["imageUrl"] as? String ?? ""

        //We now have to convert Firestore's "location" property from a GeoPoint to a CLLocationCoordinate2d
        let geoPoint = dictionary["location"] as! GeoPoint
        let latitude = geoPoint.latitude
        let longitude = geoPoint.longitude

        let location =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)

        self.init(id: id,
                  storeName: storeName,
                  imageUrl: imageUrl,
                  location: location)
    }
}
```

Then, you'll need to sort your stores by `distanceFromUser` in your `ViewController`'s `viewDidLoad`:

```swift
import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore

class ViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager?.delegate = self
        locationManager?.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()

        tableView.dataSource = self
        tableView.delegate = self

        fetchStores { (stores) in
            self.stores = stores.sorted(by: { $0.distanceFromUser < $1.distanceFromUser })
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }

    ...

}
```

Comment: ***self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))!***  and  ***let location =  CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: latitude!, longitude: longitude!)*** I had to force unwrap to run these two in the Store class to make it compile correctly, but still seems to not organize the cells from the nearest distance I even changed my simulator location to make and the arrangement of the cells was still the same

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint after that line to ensure that it is returning a distance? Additionally, did you update the `viewDidLoad` to set `stores` via `self.stores = stores.sorted(by: { $0.distanceFromUser < $1.distanceFromUser })`?

Comment: That is, set a breakpoint after `self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))!`? If `distanceFromUser` is returning a value, then sorting the `stores` in `ViewController` should rearrange your cells.

Comment: its still not rearranging the cells by the user location , is there a better way to get this rearrange the cells

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint after `self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))!` and tell me what `distanceFromUser` is equal to? This breakpoint will be called multiple times.

Comment: Similarly, you could add `print("look here!", self.distanceFromUser)` on the line after `self.distanceFromUser = (CLLocationManager().location?.distance(from: CLLocation(latitude: location.latitude, longitude: location.longitude)))! ` and check what is printed to the console. It should print multiple distances.

Comment: We just need to confirm that `self.distanceFromUser` is being set correctly.

Comment: the whole simulator crashes when I put a breakpoint after ***self.distanceFromUser*** and when I put  ***print("look here!", self.distanceFromUser)*** I get this showing multiple time in the debugger 10 times over "look here! 12251325.391829269"

Comment: The breakpoint is supposed to make the simulator stop so you can look at the code. Is the number after "look here!" the same every time or no?

Comment: yes it is for every store that I have in my database (10 stores)

Comment: Are the string values for `location` within Firestore different for each store?

Comment: yes the string value is the same copied from my firestore, would it because im using geopoint value/type to set my coordinates in firestore to cause it to not work

Comment: If the locations aren't unique on Firestore, you won't be able to sort by distance on the front end. If you set the Firestore `location`s to their unique coordinates, the Swift code should then work.

Comment: just added an image to show you how I have it set up for each location, and all my locations set are unique to their respective store, and I really appreciate all the help that you put forward into helping me

Comment: Okay, the issue is that we aren't casting the Geopoint to a `CLLocationCoordinate2d` correctly, so its defaulting to 0 degrees N, 0 degrees W for all stores. Let me look into how to cast Geopoint and get back to you.

Comment: I made a change to `convenience init(dictionary: [String : Any])`, try it out and let me know if it works for you. It seems we need to cast this value as a `GeoPoint`, I was thinking it was stored on Firestore as a `String`.

Comment: okay. Thank you so much again @DavidChopin you are the best

Comment: Not a problem homie, let me know if this cast makes the code work for you

Comment: im getting an error on  **let geoPoint = dictionary["location"] as! GeoPoint** with the error saying Use of undeclared type 'GeoPoint'  that previous comment was meant for your last message, I didn't expect you to get back to me so fast. lol

Comment: You likely have to `import Firebase` and `import FirebaseFirestore` in your `Store` file.

Comment: lol you're right okay now everything works thank you so much again for all the help @DavidChopin you're the best 